# How to distribute a test suite to a compute cluster under visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, testing, cluster-computing, xunit.net

After over a year of development we have a huge test suite for our CAD application and it's starting to impact development time running tests. Many of the tests are numeric calculations and testing many variations of the algorithms takes up significant time. It's 10min+ to run all the tests now and it cuts into dev time waiting for tests to complete impacting our productivity.

Is there any possibility with visual studio to farm out the test suite to a cluster. It would be nice to build a compute rack just for burning through all the tests quickly. Are there any off the shelf solutions for this?

We currently use XUnit and the resharper test runner.

Comment: You probably need a continuous integration server (like TeamCity: https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity which has first class support for MsBuild projects and XUnit tests)

Comment: Teamcity can run multiple builds in parallel. It can't distribute a single build or test suite across cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to manually group tests - perhaps they're in different projects and you have enough projects that parallelization by project would give you the speedup you desire?  Or can you think of a way to automatically group tests, perhaps by the class name, or namespace name, that, if run in parallel, would give you the speedup you desire?

If so,

Consider modifying the xunit resharper (or visual studio) test runner so that it would consider as valid tests only those that matched your condition on a given build/test machine.  For example, you'd have an environment variable that was a list of namespace names separated by commas, that list would be different on each build/test machine but would cover all tests, then the test runner would check that the test class was in one of the listed namespaces before considering that test valid.

Or, if you want/need to classify your test classes manually you could look at an attribute you'd place on test classes or assemblies - that would be the parallelization groups that you'd set up - and then also look at some environment variable or msbuild/devenv command line parameter you could set up on your individual build servers - and then it would only run tests, on a given build machine, where the attribute value matched the environment variable.

I got the idea from [Fixie](http://fixie.github.io/docs/) - "conventional testing for .NET" - where "conventional" means that it is a testing framework that let's you decide the "convention" by which tests are identified.  You want all classes ending in the letters "Test" to be test classes and methods ending in "Test" to be test methods?  OK.  Or, you want all methods decorated with a certain attribute to be test methods?  OK to that too.  In fact it gives you hooks where you supply code that identifies test classes, test methods, fixture behavior, etc. etc.  In Fixie my suggestion above would be quite easy to do.  But I imagine it would be just a small change to xunit's resharper runner.

On a quick look, you'd modify `IsUnitTestContainer` in [`PsiUnitTestIdentifer`](https://github.com/xunit/resharper-xunit/blob/xunit2/resharper/src/provider/UnitTestIdentifiers/PsiUnitTestIdentifier.cs#L26) which is called by `IsValidTestClass` in [`XunitPsiFileExplorer.cs`](https://github.com/xunit/resharper-xunit/blob/xunit2/resharper/src/provider/XunitPsiFileExplorer.cs#L237) to check your condition, whether it is the name of the test class or an attribute on it or on the assembly, against your environment variable (but that's just a guess).